# Technique for using indexOf when working with Java pass by Value for Parceled Object with dynamic properties?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, indexof

What kind of technique can be implemented so that the default ArrayList indexOf can be used when all properties of a particular object are dynamically changing (ie. not guaranteed to be the same since creation)

Lets say I have a class called DataManager that keeps track of Car objects in an static ArrayList.

```
public class DataManager {
   public static ArrayList<Car> carList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

In Activity 1, I add a Car Object to the carList, and then parcel the Car and send it to Activity 2 to be used.

```
public Activity1 extends Activity {
   protected void onCreate(....) {
      Car originalCar = new Car("Red","0");
      DataManager manager = new DataManager();
      manager.carList.add(originalCar);
      Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
      i.putExtra("parcelledCar",originalCar);
      startActivity(i);
   }
```

Because Java passed by value when the car object is received in Activity 2, a new object is created and the hashCode will not be the same as the original object preventing Java.Object .equals() from comparing correctly.

```
   public Activity2 {
       protected void onCreate(....) {
          Car parcelledCar = intent.getParcelableExtra("parcelledCar");

          DataManager manager = new DataManager();
          manager.carList.indexOf(parcelledCar); // RETURNs -1 
          // because the (.equals inherited from Java.Object compares
          // addresses which are not the same)
       }
   }
```

I realize that overriding the default .equals() might help in this case, but I am not sure how objects could be compared if all properties of the Car object are not guaranteed to the stay the same through the application life cycle.

For example:

```
     public class Car {
          private String colour; 
             // Different cars can have the same colour
          private int timesDriven;
            // Value is dynamic and subject to change throughout application
     }
```

Something like a GUID used in a database would be nice, but in my particular use case **I am not using a database** and I am not aware of any built in android utilities to create a GUID like identifier that is constant across parceled instances of an object (if that makes sense)?

Comment: If it is in a static class, why are you parceling it at all? Both activities would be able to read it directly from the `DataManager`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake The practical use case I am trying to use this for is a bit more complicated. In my application the DataManager is being used to overwrite and existing Object in the ArrayList, which is why it needs the indexOf, and the parcelled item is coming from an item selected from a ListView and is being used for operations in the specific activity. I was trying to generalize the problem so that it might be more useful for others on the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the `Car` object received by Activity 2 is not the same instance as the original `Car` object has nothing to do with Java pass-by-value. That is caused by the serialization/parcel done by Android. Java pass-by-value would pass the *reference* to the object by value, but it would be the *same* object instance.

If the `Car` objects are always created in the `DataManager` first, then you can add an `id` field to the `Car` object, and assign the value using an `AtomicInteger` maintained by `DataManager`. You'd then replace the `List` with a `Map` of `id` to `Car` object.

Now you can just send the `id` between activities, and lookup the `Car` object.

Basically, you've turned the `DataManager` into a simple in-memory database.

Comment: This may cause me to have to rewrite my DataManager class, but it seems a lot more elegant ! Great answer thanks!